# ORA-01722 invalid number error when I'm joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle

An error occurs while joining tables:

```
with cte1 as
( 
    select 
        p.*, 
        cast(regexp_replace(p.phone_number, '\+|\(|\)\ ', '') as varchar2(50)) as phone
    from 
        PHONE_TABLE p
    where 
        t.phone_number is not null 
    order by 
        p.phone_number asc
)
select * 
from cte1 t1
join PHONE_TABLE1 t on t.phone = t1.phone
```

I try to use convert function

Comment: Cast t.phone as well.

Comment: The cte ORDER BY doesn't order the final result set. Move it to the outer query.

Comment: In the where clause the alias `t` should be `p`

Comment: is PHONE_TABLE1.phone a number column? I suspect it is. If so, then use join PHONE_TABLE1 t on t.phone = to_char(t1.phone). Or you may use join PHONE_TABLE1 t on to_number(t.phone default null on conversion error)= t1.phone, in which case it may possibly use an index on PHONE_TABLE1.phone if there is one (which is not possible in the first solution I proposed).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to join the tables `PHONE_TABLE` and `PHONE_TABLE1` on the `phone_number` (string) and the `phone` (number) columns, respectively after removing the `+()`  characters from the `phone_number`.

You can do that using the `TRANSLATE` function (avoiding slow regular expressions):

```sql
with cte1 as
( 
  select p.*, 
         TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') as phone
  from   PHONE_TABLE p
  where  p.phone_number is not null 
  order by 
         p.phone_number asc
)
select * 
from   cte1 t1
       join PHONE_TABLE1 t on t.phone = t1.phone
```

Or, more simply, without the CTE:

```sql
select p.*,
       TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') AS phone,
       p1.*
from   phone_table p
       join PHONE_TABLE1 p1
       on TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') = p1.phone
order by 
       p.phone_number asc;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE phone_table (
  id NUMBER,
  phone_number VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE phone_table1 (
  id NUMBER,
  phone NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO phone_table (id, phone_number)
  SELECT 1, '+1(23) 456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '123456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '987654' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO phone_table1 (id, phone)
  SELECT 101, 123456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 102, 987654 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | PHONE_NUMBER | PHONE | ID | PHONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +1(23) 456 | 123456 | 101 | 123456 |
| 2 | 123456 | 123456 | 101 | 123456 |
| 3 | 987654 | 987654 | 102 | 987654 |

---

If you have a string in `PHONE_TABLE` that, after removing those characters, is not going to be a valid number:

```sql
INSERT INTO phone_table (id, phone_number) VALUES (4, '987-654');
```

Then the above will fail as the implicit conversion from string to number will fail in the `JOIN`. You can solve that by explicitly comparing on strings:

```sql
select p.*,
       TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') AS phone,
       p1.*
from   phone_table p
       join PHONE_TABLE1 p1
       on TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') = TO_CHAR(p1.phone)
order by 
       p.phone_number asc
```

or, from Oracle 12, explicitly converting the string to a number and using the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` option:

```sql
select p.*,
       TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0') AS phone,
       p1.*
from   phone_table p
       join PHONE_TABLE1 p1
       on TO_NUMBER(
            TRANSLATE(p.phone_number, '0+() ', '0')
            DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR
          ) = p1.phone
order by 
       p.phone_number asc
```

Which outputs the same.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zEbo33CI)